# Getting latests messages depending on time query

Tags: php, iphone, database, sqlite

I have a table which has fields
i AM Saving messages for each type of user. so idValue is different for all the users.

> idValue    message    time_added    type

I am using following query to get at start

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idValue = 'iO9I22-AOI' ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 30
```

This query gets the latest 30 messages (Kindly check if this query is alright).

Now upon button click , i want to get 30 or variable more messages. E.g If first query got 30 latest messages , now on button click I need to get 30 more latests messages but previous than the first 30.

I am not getting , how am i suppose to make its query.

Comment: MySQL LIMIT allows for selection of rows between a given range. 
So 
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE idValue = 'iO9I22-AOI' ORDER BY time_added DESC LIMIT 30, 30 would bring the next 30 rows from the 30th record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the LIMIT on your query

let the page has a 'next' link which can generate pagination.
e.g clicking on
`page.php?pagenum=2`
would change the LIMIT to `LIMIT 30,30`

when you click on
`page.php?pagenum=3`
would make `LIMIT 60,30`

so the formula to change the LIMIT is
(pagenum-1)*30